# Updating in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

There is a collection in mongoDB:

```
info = {
    "name":"me",
    "note":[
        {"date":"Dec.01",
         "item":"01",
        },
        {"date":"Dec.02",
         "item":"02",
        }
    ]
}
```

Using pymongo, how do I push `{"date":"Dec.03","item":"03"}` to the key *"note"* directly?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `$push`[1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform a regular update operation using pymongo, and use the `$push` operator provided by MongoDB itself. So something like this:

```
collection.update({"name":"me"},{$push:{"note":{"date":"Dec.03","item":"03"}}});
```

Here's some documentation on the `$push` operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Also, note how the `$push` operator is actually part of MongoDB itself, so most packages that use Mongo, like pymongo in your case, **will** support this operator.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `$addToSet` operator (see [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)).